# Countifs to match OR conditions?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, countif

I have the following countifs formula

```
=COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$848,Summary!$F5,'Report'!$G$2:$G$848,$Q$10,$G$2:$G$848,$Q$11)
```

on my sheet, Q10 = Monday, Q11 = Tuesday
On 'Report', G2:G848 contains login data

Objective: I need the total count from Report that are either on Monday(Q10) or Tuesday (Q11)

With the current formula I have, countifs is looking for rows that has Monday and Tuesday in the row, which is a wrong.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably F2:F848 is also on Report sheet? Try this

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS('Report'!$F$2:$F$848,Summary!$F5,'Report'!$G$2:$G$848,$Q$10:$Q$11))`

Assumes formula resides on same sheet as the Q10 and Q11 values....

The COUNTIFS function will return an "array" of 2 values, one for Monday (Q10) and one for Tuesday(Q11), then SUMPRODUCT just sums the 2 values to give you the total for both days

Comment: New issue - I used that, and ran it on a list that do not have Monday or Tuesday. The value returned was greater than the number of rows that has data on.

Comment: @Kyle - do you mean you are trying to find the number of rows which have anything but Monday or Tuesday? For that you need to use a different syntax,i.e.`=COUNTIFS('Report'!$F$2:$F$848,Summary!$F5,'Report'!$G$2:$G$848,"<>"&$Q$10,'Report'!$G$2:$G$848,"<>"&$Q$11)`......or are you saying you ran the same formula (but with different ranges) and got an incorrect result? If it's the latter can you post the formula - it should be impossible for the formula to return more than the number of rows unless Q10=Q11. To cope with that you could switch to SUMPRODUCT- see next comment

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(('Report'!$F$2:$F$848=Summary!$F5)*ISNUMBER(MATCH,'Report'!$G$2:$G$848,$Q$10:$Q$11,0)))`

Answer (score 1):

```
=COUNTIF('Report'!$G$2:$G$848,"Q10")+COUNTIF('Report'!$G$2:$G$848,"Q11")
```

This assumes that `'Report'!$G$2:$G$848` contains the `Q10` and `Q11` values you're talking about.

Comment: Is there no way of adding them in 1 Countif ? What about using the OR function within countif?

Comment: There probably is, but you didn't indicate that that mattered.  I.e. keep it simple.

Comment: Q10 and Q11 were cell references??  That wasn't clear from the question.  I thought you were looking for the literal values "Q10" and "Q11".

Comment: Barry figured my question and provided the answer I was looking for. thanks anyway :)